# Add tags in Elasticsearch using logstash jdbc plugin

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-jdbc

Suppose we have 2 table

1) Customer (CustID, Name)

2) Purchases (Cust_ID, Purchase_ID)

There is one to many (1:n) relation between (1) & (2).

Now using logstash I want to insert this data from sql into elasticsearch. The problem is if I take join of two tables then it will insert multiple rows/json records for a single customer. I wish to insert data as follows.

```
{
Cust_ID : 101,
Purchase_ID : [ 1001, 2003, 20006]
}
```

but it comes as

```
{
Cust_ID : 101,
Purchase_ID : 1001
},
{
Cust_ID : 101,
Purchase_ID : 2003
}
```

I found the link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html useful. But it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Every row your SQL query returns becomes a document in Elasticsearch.  So, change your query to return the row you want.  It may be that you need to concatenate your purchaseIds into one field, and then use logstash's mutate->split to turn them into an array.